# Upload video on website and keep it secured ? (Django)

Tags: python, html, django, video, html5-video

For the school project I've been working on, the client asked for video uploading, but due to privacy, they wanted to secure the video to be shown only for signed users.

I made the page to be secured, but uploading video was a bit of problem.

I was thinking about youtube prvacy enhanced mode, but because various users will be uploading, this wasn't a good way to do.

So, I was wondering,

1. Can server / host or webpage handle the size of the videos uploaded by users ?
2. Would html5 video tag be ok for this?
3. Would there be any other good option in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see some similar questions here also but the first thing is to define what you mean by securing the video:

- if you just need to limit access then there are a number of mechanisms you can use such as:

  - Use signed URLs - here is an AWS example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html
  - Obfuscating the URL - you need to be aware that this can be seen as security issue, depending on how you do it as the user may worry they don't know where the URL is going
  - Session or token based authentication - this will allow you only make the page or asset available to authenticated users. There is a good summary of the difference here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/92123
- if you also need to protect against a user with valid access, who might copy and re-distribute the video without your permission then you generally need to look at a solution that encrypts the video.

For the last point, the reason this is needed is because even if you obfuscate the video download or streaming process, ultimately the video has to be downloaded to the device for it to play and there is no effective way to stop it being copied.

To address this the usual approach is to encrypt the video and to provide the key to trusted users either directly, or via a DRM system.

The advantage of providing it directly is that it is simple and cheap. The disadvantage is that an untrusted user can share the key or the decrypted content.

The advantage of a DRM system is that the trusted user, and even the trusted users application and OS, don't ever see the key, as the key is itself encrypted by the DRM system. If a DRM system is hacked, then it is likely there will be bigger targets than your content, and the DRM provider should also work to counter the breach quickly. The disadvantage of a DRM system is the extra complexity and the cost.

Ultimately, security is about putting up barriers and the number and complexity of the barriers you will want set up generally depends on the likely value of your content to an attacker, so the decision is usually determined by your own particular solution and the content you want to protect.